# C# TrimEnd() equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a statement like

```
bicCode.ToUpper().TrimEnd('X');
```

I want to rewrite this in javascript

```
response.data.toUpperCase().??
```

How to write trimend function in javascript?

Comment: @Equalsk that's not really the same behaviour as TrimEnd.

Comment: Why don't you try the following: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28464/trim-certain-characters-from-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @DavidSherret You're right I worded it badly but it wasn't meant to directly answer the question, it was more a problem that OP showed no effort. I'm not even a JavaScript guy but after reading that thread I wrote TrimEnd in about 2 minutes: https://jsfiddle.net/cgvw5x9e/ and if I can do it then OP can.

Comment: this isn't a duplicate...

Comment: @Equalsk you should post that as an answer. An answer has already been accepted, but it is only the empty argument overload of TrimEnd, your fiddle adds the missing piece

Comment: @Jakotheshadows Can't answer locked posts.

Comment: yeah, god forbid people be able to easily find useful information on a site designed to help people do just that. Better to make a superficial examination of the post, incorrectly conclude that its a duplicate, and close it thus wasting the productivity of the people (including yourself) who contributed to comments and answers and robbing the OP of a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

> response.data.toUpperCase().replace(/\s+$/g, '');